# In JBoss 7 how can you limit the number of threads started with @Asyncronous for a specific bean

Tags: asynchronous, jboss7.x

I have a process that I want to run serially, but in a different thread. How can I accomplish that in JBoss 7? The obvious answer would be an @Asyncronous EJB method where the EJB is configured to only have one thread running at a time (the others requests would be in queue).

How can that be best accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a great way of achieving this is using a combination of Singleton + Asynchronous annotations from EJB 3.1, you can also use the AccessTimeout annotation to provide wait timeout for the queued calls and finally you can even use Lock annotation to control READ,WRITE locking on this if you want:

```
@Singleton
public class SingletonAsyncProcessor{

@Asynchronous
@AccessTimeout(5000) //times out after 5 seconds
public Future<String> addJobToQueue(String jobName) {
```

Also notice that you can use most of these annotations at class level(all methods will be async) or method level. You can even run EJB 3.1 in the web container.

EJB 3.1 ROCKS.

Regards.

Comment: It is an approach, but the problem is that it means the queue must be clear in 5 seconds or the client gets an exception. I would rather it behave like a single thread executor service, where additional requests just wait.

Comment: The asynchronous singleton does handle requests serially, but not necessarily in a single thread. Running a simple example on JBoss AS 7.1.3, I can see that each request is handled by a different thread from the EJB thread pool. If you really require a single thread, you have to configure the thread pool in an implementation dependent way.

Comment: Well Yishai, you can set the queue to never timeout if you want. Just set the parameter on the @AccessTimeout to -1 and you wont get any exeption related to wait timeouts.